# How to catch Linkedin Javascript sdk init error?

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

If, for any reason, the api_key in IN.init isn't valid the console is giving:

"Uncaught Error: You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration.".

Is there any way for me to catch this error and do something with the information?

Edit 1: Here is the example of an async script load and initialization

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '//platform.linkedin.com/in.js?async=true',
                dataType: 'script',
                success: function ( ) {
                    IN.init({
                        api_key: "MY_API_KEY",
                        onLoad: "onLinkedInLoad",
                        authorize: true
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('err');

                }
            });
```

Comment: What is `IN.init`, I can’t find that under https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk // If you are embedding the SDK the way this page shows, I doubt there is any chance for you to catch this. The SDK code itself reads that data that is passed as text content of the script element, so there is no way for you to interfere or wrap anything around it (like a try/catch maybe.)

Comment: @CBroe I added sample code I'm trying to use.

Comment: So you tried try/catch directly around the IN.init call? Looks like they are using `throw new Error('...')` in the SDK code, so that should be catchable I think.

Comment: I tried this:
try {
                            IN.init({
                                api_key: "MY_API_KEY",
                                onLoad: "onLinkedInLoad",
                                authorize: true
                            });
                        } catch (e) {
                            console.log(e);
                        }

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with my catch clause?

Comment: Looks ok to me ... Dunno if the error is maybe thrown somewhere else, somehow decoupled from this in an async operation, ... // What is your scenario here, where it would be important to catch this error via scripting? Some sort of CMS, where users enter their own API key or sth. like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150312/discussion-between-milan-vuckovic-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way `LinkedIn` is handling the `IN.init` (by adding a `script` to the page that will throw exceptions from within) you can't catch actually any exceptions no matter where you will place a `try catch` block.

The only thing that you could do is to have a `window.onerror` handler or a error listener on window which will catch a generic  `Script error` if the `IN.init` fails.

```js
window.onerror = function(e) {
  if (e == 'Script error.') {
    console.log('There is a chace IN.init failed.');
  }
}
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '//platform.linkedin.com/in.js?async=true',
  dataType: 'script',
  success: function() {
    IN.init({
      api_key: "MY_API_KEY",
      onLoad: "onLinkedInLoad",
      authorize: true
    });
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log('err');

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a try catch around the call.  Therefore catching the exception to see more about why it's throwing an error. It all depends on who and what you're trying to do with the error and the API call.

Comment: I tried doing that but it didn't work. I couldn't catch the error that API was giving.

Answer (score 0):

Milan is onto something here.

I think if you do something like this

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '//platform.linkedin.com/in.js?async=true',
   dataType: 'script',
   success: function () {
     IN.init({
        api_key: "MY_API_KEY",
        onLoad: "onLinkedInLoad",
        authorize: true
     });
},
   error: function () {
        console.log('err');
}
}).done(function (data) { });
```

With the key being the .done at the end.  This will run no matter what and if data is populated you'll either have an error, success, or nothing.